# How we can use web3.js library in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, ethereum, web3js, ganache

I want to use web3.js with Vue.js to connect to ganache and make a transaction.

I don't know where I can write code for making a connection and then make a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install web3
```

Then, simply import it in your vue components. More info can be found in [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js)

After importing, try to use it like this:

```js
var web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');
console.log(web3);
```

Comment: I use a statement import web3 from 'web3' but it gives me an error like web3' is declared but its value is never read. Don't know what to do.

Comment: @BilalSakhawat That's a warning, not an error.